# What happens if I didn’t use my Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I got my Schengen visa from Belgium Embassy for doing exam. I got approved and gave me one single entry for 10 days.

But now I have changed the dates of the exam

My questions what happens if I didn’t go. 
And what happens if I go but didn’t do my exam
Especially the employees had asked me to come back to embassy after getting back from  Belgium which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens.

You don't have to go because you got a visa.

The reason they asked you to visit the embassy is to verify that you really left Schengen area. It may be a good idea to call them, tell them that you didn't travel, and ask if you should come by with your passport to prove that you didn't.

Comment: Thanks vidarlo so I can use the visa as tourism and get back with no issue?

Comment: What kind of visa is it? Is it valid for tourism? Changing the purpose of the trip *may* impact future applications, as you essentially mislead the embassy to get it.

Comment: Visa type C, that’s my concern should I inform them that I have changed exam date. Or I use the visa and go to Belgium for two days and apply another time for visa

Comment: Inform them of the change and apply for a new visa for the new date seems like the logical conclusion.